# print 2d array vhdl

Tags: vhdl, fpga

How do I print matrix_a(1,1) on the console? The report command I commented does not work.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity ent is

end ent;

architecture Behavioral of ent is

type my_matrix is array(integer range 0 to 3, integer range 0 to 3) of integer;
signal matrix_a : my_matrix;    

begin
    matrix_a(1,1) <= 4;
    --report "signal signal_d is " & integer'image((matrix_a(1,1)));


end Behavioral;
```

Comment: The reserved word **report** may not occur there outside a comment, it is a syntax error. A report statement is not a concurrent statement, and can only be used in a place appropriate for a sequential statement, a subprogram or a process statement.  (An assertion statement contains a report *clause*). "does not work" should be 'does not analyze' (which some simulator vendors may call compile), or you could supply the actual error message.

Comment: What should I write instead of `report` in order to printout on the console `matrix_a(1,1)`? Thanks

Comment: The only way to access STANDARD_OUTPUT is through a report statement, which needs to be in a construct appropriate for a sequential statement, for instance in a process statement as Brian suggests in his answer. Or you could use an assertion statement which uses a report clause instead.

Comment: Which tool? Some tools support file I/O.

Answer (score 0):

When do you expect that `report` to run?

You have placed it in the concurrent statement region of your architecture : everything there is effectively a process, scheduled according to specific rules; for example, the concurrent assignment `matrix_a(1,1) <= 4;` will run once at startup, and whenever any of its values change (i.e. never again as they are all literal constants).

But there is nothing to make the "report" run.

Now if you embed it explicitly in a process, sensitive to changes in `matrix_a`, then it will run at start and whenever matrix_a changes. So try this in place of the commented line:

```
process (matrix_a) is    -- this list controls the process running
begin
   report "signal signal_d is " & integer'image(matrix_a(1,1));
end process;
```

Comment: Hi. In this way the program does not print on the console  the value of `matrix_a(1,1)`. How do I print on the console the value of `matrix_a(1,1)` when I run the synthesis? Thanks.

Comment: You could note that file I/O is not supported in synthesis other than for purposes of defining default values or  the value of constants during elaboration. Or did you mean run the simulation instead of 'run the synthesis'? Brian's process works in simulation although I'd personally modify it to eliminate reporting the default value (INTEGER'LEFT here): *ent.vhdl:18:8:@0ms:(report note): signal signal_d is -2147483648
ent.vhdl:18:8:@0ms:(report note): signal signal_d is 4*

Comment: ok I see. I'm facing another problem. I'm not able to write the value of `matrix_a(1,1)` to a file. I wrote this code:
    'process
    
    variable line_var : line;
    file text_var : text;
    variable num : integer := 40;
    
      
    begin
    m_a(1,1) <= 4;
        file_open(text_var,"C:\Users\Tommy\Desktop\write.txt", write_mode);
        write(line_var, integer'image(m_a(1,1)));
        writeline(text_var, line_var);              -- write line_var into the file
        file_close(text_var);'

but when I open write.txt file I read _<non-const>_